# Runtime error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'

Tags: python

I was solving a HackerRank problem and the code runs perfectly in my machine but it is showing a runtime error in the HackerRank editor:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    ele = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'
```

My code is as follows:

```py
n = int(input())
num = []
for i in range(0,n):
    ele = int(input())
    num.append(ele)
```

Comment: `input()` takes in a full line. This means that you have to split the input using `input().split()` to get a list of the space separated numbers. Map them to an interger by doing `map(int, input().split())` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = map(int,input().split())
num = []
for i in range(0,n):
    ele = int(input())
    num.append(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most like the input format that you expected is different.

When you write `int(input())`, you are assuming the line of input is a single integer but from the error message, it is multiple integers separated by a space.

```
for i in range(n):
    num = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

should work as we converted the line to a list by splitting using the spaces.